# Can only Formulas be hidden in an Excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can an Excel sheet be maintained in such a way that the cells where data entry is required therein are editable, however users can't view the formulas put in the other cells.

I am using Excel 2003.

Comment: You could do this by locking the cells with formulas. 
https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/cells/hide_formulas.php

Comment: Thank you  Christofer. The contents at the link were useful and worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by locking the cells with formulas: [How to hide formulas](http://techonthenet.com/excel/cells/hide_formulas.php)

Select the cells than need to stay editable, right click and select Format Cells. On the Protection tab,  cells in the spreadsheet will be "Locked" by default. Uncheck "Locked" for the ones that need to be editable.

Select the cells with formulas to be hidden, right click go the Protection details, and select "Hidden".

Now, go the the workbook Review tab, and select "Protect Sheet". You can enter a password if you think you need to.